# Finding UMVUE of $p^s$ in Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ follows Bernoulli distribution $B(1,p)$,

then what is the UMVUE of $p^s$ and $p^s + (1-p)^{n-s}$?

I suppose I should use the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem. Now $\overline{X}$ is a sufficient and complete statistic, I need to find a function of $\overline{X}$ whose expectation is $p^s$ and  $p^s + (1-p)^{n-1}$. But I don't know how to find such a function.

Any hint would be welcome!

Comment: Can you explain the not-very-very-usual naming "UMVUE" ? (Unidentified Main Value Upon Expectation ?). And at the same time give a reference to Lehmann-Scheffé theorem, not very well known either...

Comment: @JeanMarie UMVUE means Uniformly Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimate, which is the unbiased estimate with lowest variance among all unbiased estimates. L-S theorem suggests that if $T$ is a complete and sufficient statistics of $\theta$, $f(T)$ is a function of $T$ and $E(f(T)) = g(\theta)$, then $f(T)$ is the unique UMVUE of $g(\theta)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie so basically I need to find the function $f$ which meets the requirement.

Comment: @JeanMarie : UMVUE is a standard term.

Comment: But $\overline{X}$ is not a sufficient statistic. $T = \sum X_i$ is, isn't it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687375/how-to-find-umvue-of-thetak-with-bernoulli-distribution?rq=1.

Comment: @Hendrra : Either of those is a sufficient statistic. They are equivalent in the sense of both generating the same sigma-algebra, so if either is sufficient then the other must be as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $$\operatorname{E}(X_1\cdots X_s) = p^s$$ if $s$ is an integer and $1\le s\le n,$ and if $1\le n-s\le n$, then $$\operatorname{E}(X_1\cdots X_s + (1-X_{s+1})\cdots(1-X_n)) = p^s + (1-p)^{n-s}.$$

The estimators that you need are the conditional expected values
$$
\operatorname{E}(X_1\cdots X_s\mid \overline X_n) \text{ and } \operatorname{E}((1-X_{s+1})\cdots(1-X_n)\mid \overline{X}_n).
$$
Because $\overline X_n$ is sufficient, the conditional expected values above do not depend on $p$ and are therefore observable and can be used as estimators.

\begin{align}
& \operatorname{E}\left(X_1\cdots X_s \mid \overline X_n = \frac x n\right) \\
= {} &  \Pr\left( X_1\cdots X_s = 1 \mid X_1+\cdots+X_n = x \right) = \frac{\dbinom {n-s}{n-x}}{\dbinom n x}
\end{align}
So the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem says the UMVUE of $p^s$ is
$$
\frac{\dbinom{n-s}{n-(X_1+\cdots+X_n)}}{\dbinom n {X_1+\cdots+X_n}}.
$$

Comment: That's so neat. Thanks!

Comment: Sir, I'm wondering, if the observed value of $X_1 + \ldots + X_n = x$ is less than $s$, the conditional expectation would reduce to zero. I think that wouldn't make a legitimate UMVUE anymore; so is it UMVUE only when the observed value of $x$ is greater than $s$?

Comment: Yes: There is no unbiased estimator of of $p^s$ based on any sample of fewer than $s$ observations. The expected value of a function $g$ of $n$ observations is $$ \operatorname{E}(g(X_1,\ldots,X_n)) = \sum_{x_1=0}^1 \cdots \sum_{x_n=0}^1 g(x_1,\ldots,x_n) p^{x_1+\cdots+x_n} (1-p_1)^{n-(x_1+\cdots+x_n)} , $$ and that is an $n$th-degree polynomial function of $p.$ Algebra tells us that that cannot be equal to $p^s$ for more than $s$ values of $p.$ In order for it to be an unbiased estimator of $p,$ it would have to remain equal to $p^s$ as $p$ goes from $0$ to $1. \qquad$

Comment: There would still be an MLE of $p^s,$ and that is $\displaystyle \left( \frac {X_1+\cdots+X_n} n \right)^s.$ For $n\ge p,$ I think maybe the MLE might have a uniformly smaller mean square error that the UMVUE, but I haven't checked that.

Comment: WAIT!! If $n<s$ then there is no unbiased estimator. But if you meant merely that the observed sum is less than $s$, even though $n\ge s$, that would not prevent it from being an unbiased estimator of $p^s.$ An unbiased estimator is correct on average, but in some cases one knows based only on the data that the case one is looking at is not an average case. That is a known problem with unbiasedness.

Comment: thanks! Now I understand:)

Comment: @MichaelHardy: On the second equation, should either the left side or the right side be adjusted? That is, either throw away $X_1 \ldots X_s$ from the LHS, or add $p^s$ on the RHS?

Comment: @Just_to_Answer : Done. $\qquad$

Comment: Why $\Pr\left( X_1\cdots X_s = 1 \mid X_1+\cdots+X_n = x \right) = \frac{\dbinom {n-s}{n-x}}{\dbinom n x}$? Shouldn't that be $\Pr\left( X_1\cdots X_s = 1 \mid X_1+\cdots+X_n = x \right) = \frac{\dbinom {n-s}{x-s}}{\dbinom n x}$

Comment: @НикитаВасильев : Those two are equal via the identity $\dbinom n k = \dbinom n {n-k}. \qquad$