# Maximum Likelihood Estimator and MVUE for theta-squared

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ denote a random sample of size $n\ge4$ from Bernoulli ($\theta$) distribution where $$0 < \theta < 1$$ is the success probability.

How would I derive the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of $\theta^2?$

Also, with $\hat{\theta}=Y_1Y_2$ being unbiased for $\theta^2$, and $U=\sum(Y_i)$ is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$, how would I "Rao-Blackwellize" $\hat{\theta}$ and explicitly derive the conditional expectation, $E[\hat{\theta}|U]$, to come up with the minimum variance unbiased estimator (MVUE) for $\theta^2?$

These questions are confusing me because it is asking for $\theta^2$ instead of just $\theta$. If someone could please show/tell me what to do/steps to figuring this out that would be amazing!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Expectation of Bernoulli R.V.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2881669/conditional-expectation-of-bernoulli-r-v) By invariance property, MLE of any function $g(\theta)$ of $\theta$ is $g(\hat\theta_{MLE})$ where $\hat\theta_{MLE}$ is MLE of $\theta$. Also note that $\sum Y_i$ is a complete statistic.

Comment: Yes, that helped with my second question. Do you think you could provide more detail on how I would go about finding the MLE of theta^2? Thanks.