# Finding MVUE for $p^k$ - cross check solution

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

(Warning, long text)  I've been given the following instructions;

> Let $\boldsymbol X = \mathit X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from binomial distribution $b(N,p)$, with PMF $f(x;p) = {N\choose x} \cdot p^x \cdot (1-p)^{N-x}$, where $N$ is a known positive integer. Find the MVUE for the parameter $g(p)=p^k$

I've come up with a solution and a result, but I'm only starting getting into statistics, so I would really appreciate it if someone took the time to look at the following. Here it goes;

I'm going to use the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem, by finding an unbiased estimator of $g(p)$ that depends on the sample through a sufficient and copmplete statistic of the parameter $p$. Such a statistic is $T(\boldsymbol X)=\sum_{i=0}^N X_i$, which follows the binomial distribution $b(nN,p)$. So, I need to find a function $U(\boldsymbol X) = g(T(\boldsymbol X))$, such that $E\big[U(\boldsymbol X)\big] = E\big[g\big(T(\boldsymbol X)\big)\big] = p^k$. Solving this equation;
$$E\big[g\big(T(\boldsymbol X)\big)\big] = \sum_{x=0}^{nN} {nN\choose x} \cdot p^x \cdot (1-p)^{nN-x} = \sum_{x=0}^{nN} {nN\choose x} \cdot \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^x \cdot (1-p)^{nN} = p^k \implies$$
$$\sum_{x=0}^{nN} {nN\choose x} \cdot \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^x \cdot p^{-k} \cdot \left(1-p\right)^k = \left(1-p\right)^{k-nN} \implies$$

$$\sum_{x=0}^{nN} {nN\choose x} \cdot \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{x-k}  =\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)^{nN-k}$$
Now, if I denote $\frac{p}{1-p} = \rho$, I get to $1-p= \frac{1}{1+\rho}$, so $\frac{1}{1-p}=1+\rho$. Therefore, I have got to $$\sum_{x=0}^{nN} {nN\choose x} \cdot \rho^{x-k} = (1+\rho)^{nN-k} = \sum_{y=0}^{nN-k} {nN-k\choose y} \rho^y$$
using the binomial theorem, and substituting $y$ with $x-k$, I get to $$\sum_{x=0}^{nN} {nN\choose x} \cdot \rho^{x-k} = \sum_{x=k}^{nN-k} {nN-k\choose x-k} \cdot \rho^{x-k}$$ If I know equalize the coefficients of $\rho^{x-k}$ on each Sum, I have that;

$g(x)= \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & x=0, 1, ... k-1 \\
      \frac{{nN-k\choose x-k}}{{nN\choose x}} & x=k, k+1, ..., nN)\\
\end{array} 
\right.$

This can be further simplified to $g(x)=\frac{(nN-k)! \cdot x!}{nN! \cdot (x-k)!}$, So I have fianally got to my result; The MVUE for the parameter $g(p)=p^k$ is the statistic $$U(\boldsymbol X) = \frac{(nN-k)! \cdot T(\boldsymbol X)!}{nN! \cdot \big(T(\boldsymbol X)-k\big)!},     x = k, k+1, ..., nN$$ (The statistic $T(\boldsymbol X) = \sum_{i=0}^N X_i$, as stated in the beginning).

---

First of all, I am not so confident about my result because, it's still the beginning of my journey through the course, and secondly, isn't this a very fussy function?
Anyway, thanks in advance to anyone that may take the time to point out any mistake or confirm the solution, and again sorry for the long text!

Comment: You can compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2687375/321264